# ASPNET Core returning file fails using IE11? Content_Length Mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller method that returns a file, and in all browsers this works apart from IE11.  In IE11 i get a 500 server exception.  In my `dotnet run` console command, i get this message.

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HLAA8HNC511P", Request id "0HLAA8HNC511P:00000007": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
>   application. System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length
>   mismatch: too few bytes written (0 of 9283).

I cannot seem to catch the exception either, even by adding the `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` call in my `Startup.cs` file.

My controller method is very simple and looks like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync([FromRoute] long id, [FromRoute] long fileId, [FromQuery] FilePreviewModel previewOptions)
{
    var entity = await _fileService.GetAsync(Module, id, fileId);

    var fileName = "MEARS 2000 LOGO";
    var contentType = "image/gif";

    // this is a byte array
    var data = entity.Data.Content;

    // return file content
    return File(data, contentType, fileName);
}
```

In IE11, the request and response headers look like this.

[image]

In chrome, my headers look like so.

[image]

I have updated my dotnet SDK to version 2.1.3.

Anyone know what could possibly be going on??

Comment: What is the type of `entity.Data.Content`? Is it a `Stream` or a `byte[]` array.

Comment: `byte[]` (updated post with this detail) sorry didnt make that clear

Comment: This might be related to https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6875. Does adding `Context.Request.Headers.Remove("If-Modified-Since");` to your action prevent the exception from happening?

Comment: @Wazner I think that issue was fixed in 2.1. OP is using 2.1.3

Comment: I tried this on 2.0.3 and it didnt work.  I have upgraded to 2.1.3 and it still doesnt work.  I have tried adding `HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("Content-Length");` and `HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("If-Modified-Since");` before i call and return `File`, but still get same problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I think this question deserves more attention...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, instead, it won't throw the error always.

Managed to solve it by removing the headers inside the action like this:

```
[HttpGet("{container}/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string container, string id)
{
    /* remove both of these headers... put a warning here to apply the fix after dotnet team distributes the fix. */
    HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("If-Modified-Since");
    HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("If-None-Match");

    var _fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo($"{container}/{id}");
    if (!_fileInfo.Exists || string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        /* return a default file here */

    var last = _fileInfo.LastModified;
    /* ... some code removed for brevity */

    return base.File(_fileInfo.CreateReadStream(), MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(id.Substring(id.LastIndexOf("."))), id, lastModified: _lastModified, entityTag: _etag);
}
```

`dotnet --info` shows `version : 2.0.4`